# Return JSON without header in Laravel 5.1 middleware

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, header

I want to remove header information from laravel 5.1 response. I have used middleware for filter output.

```
$response = $next($request);
dd($response);
```

It gives me out put with header information. Check attached screen shot.
[image]

How to read either #data or how to remove Header information from $response?

Because when I try to json_decode it shows 'null'

I want JSON to be send only so I have use it with my application.

Comment: Provide some more details, Question is not much clear

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

```
return response()->json($response)->getData()
```

It will remove header, exception data from the object.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution

`$response->getData()` or `$response->getContent()`

`getData()/getContent()` function returns only data without any extra parameter (headers)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your method to return a **json** object your can use

`return response()->json($response, $status);`

Note that you can add an optional parameter **$status**

for **HTTP status codes** which can be very useful if you're using **Javascript** to manipulate the returned data and throw any necessary exceptions.